# Clang Tool Cannot Find Required Libraries on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: c++, ubuntu, clang, llvm-clang

I am building a simple C++ Clang tool program called `ClangEx` using CMake on Ubuntu 16.10 x64.

The project has a single `main.cpp` file. It's contents are as follows:

```
#include "clang/Frontend/FrontendActions.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/CommonOptionsParser.h"
#include "clang/Tooling/Tooling.h"
#include "llvm/Support/CommandLine.h"

using namespace clang::tooling;
using namespace llvm;

static llvm::cl::OptionCategory MyToolCategory("my-tool options");
static cl::extrahelp CommonHelp(CommonOptionsParser::HelpMessage);

static cl::extrahelp MoreHelp("\nMore help text...");

int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  CommonOptionsParser OptionsParser(argc, argv, MyToolCategory);
  ClangTool Tool(OptionsParser.getCompilations(),
                 OptionsParser.getSourcePathList());
  return Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory<clang::SyntaxOnlyAction>().get());
}
```

---

It builds successfully with CMake but when I use it to analyze an example C++ program, I get the following error:

```
$ ./ClangEx SandwichBar.cpp --
In file included from /home/bmuscede/SandwichBar.cpp:11:
In file included from /home/bmuscede/SandwichBar.h:14:
In file included from /home/bmuscede/Customers/Sandwich.h:15:
In file included from /home/bmuscede/Customers/../Capital/Recipe.h:14:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/string:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/bits/char_traits.h:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/bits/postypes.h:40:
In file included from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/6.2.0/../../../../include/c++/6.2.0/cwchar:44:
/usr/include/wchar.h:39:11: fatal error: 'stdarg.h' file not found
# include <stdarg.h>
          ^
1 error generated.
Error while processing /home/bmuscede/SandwichBar.cpp.
```

---

I was able to find [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/llvm-defaults/+bug/1242300) but installing `clang-3.9` doesn't seem to help my situation.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: See [a question I filed on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/383029/clang-version-3-3-lacks-headers) years ago.  Clang++ just seems systematically borked on Ubuntu.

Comment: You can't expect the clang C++ library to be compatible with g++.

Comment: It does seem that there are a lot of difficulties with Clang on Ubuntu but I haven't been able to pin down an answer. I thought I'd post here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem arises sometimes when you have both gcc and clang installed. By default `C_INCLUDE_PATH` and `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` are set to search gcc's own include files and don't include clang's include files. And Clang needs the clang specefic include files. To fix try:

```
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=$C_INCLUDE_PATH:"<clang_include_path>"    
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=$CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH:"<clang_include_path>"
```

where `<clang_include_path>` is usually `/usr/lib/clang/<version>/include`, but can vary based on your installation. On my system, since I built clang from source it's totally different.

If you permanently want to export the two flags, add the same two lines to `~/.bashrc`

Hope that helps.

Comment: What if one wanted to transparently flip back and forth?  I have more than one working editor, terminal, ... so why not have two compilers?

Comment: What I do is export the INCLUDE_PATH on the terminal I am planning on doing clang related stuff. 

I won't claim to be an expert on the design decisions of how they should work. But what I suggested my friend was to write a bash function to switch back and fourth between include paths and it seemed to work for him.

Comment: Thanks for your post Nishant. I'll have to try this as soon as I get home!